# Mostrar datos de una BBDD dependiendo de valores de otra tabla

Tags: php, html5

Tengo la siguiente BBDD con usuario, contraseña y si tienen distintos OS (con un boolean para cada OS):

[image]

Quiero crear otra tabla en la que haya un registro de noticias y el OS al que pertenecen.
Una noticia puede pertenecer a dos OS.

La pregunta es: ¿Cual sería la forma más fácil de mostrar las noticias dependiendo de los OS del usuario activo en esa session?

Comment: Yo sacaría las columnas de los OS de esa tabla. Y crearía tres tablas más: 1. **`tabla_os`** con las columnas: `id_os, os_name`; 2. **`tabla_noticias`** con las columnas: `id_noticia, noticia`; 3. **`noticias_so`** con las columnas `id_noticia, id_os`. Esta última tabla permitirá indicar mediante `id_os` que una misma noticia pueda pertenecer a varios `os`. Sería una tabla asociativa para registrar las relaciones muchos a muchos, o sea, una noticia puede pertenecer a varios so, y varios so pueden pertenecer a la misma noticia.

Answer (score 1):

Acá ahí varios temas, lo primero que tienes que hacer es replantear el diseño de las tablas y sus relaciones, según entendí quieres lo siguiente:

Un usuario puede tener 1 o muchos sistemas operativos y un sistema operativo puede estar relacionado con 1 o muchos usuarios. (relación m x n)

Una noticia puede tener 1 o muchos (incluye 2) sistemas operativos y un sistema operativo puede tener 1 o muchas noticias (relación de m x n).

Tabla Usuario:
id, nombre, password, etc.

Tabla Sistemas Operativos:
id,  nombre, sigla (lo que se necesite)

Tabla Noticias: 
id, titulo, texto, etc.

y nos quedan pendiente las relaciones que por regla y al normalizarlas si es de tipo n x m, implica una tabla intermedia que contenga los ids de las tablas relacionadas por ejemplo:

Usuario: id (+)

UsuarioSistemaOperativo: usuario_id (+) y sistema_operativo_id (*)

SistemaOperativo: id (*)

e igual para la otra relación.

Si necesitas ver las noticias filtradas por los sistemas operativos que ha seleccionado el usuario la consulta sería algo así, y sin darle muchas vueltas:

```
Select * from Noticia n 
join NoticiaSistemaOperativo nso on n.id = nso.noticia_id
where nso.sistema_operativo_id in (
select uso.sistema_operativo_id from Usuario u 
join  UsuarioSistemaOperativo uso on u.id = uso.usuario_id
where u.id = XXXX
)
```